# Look for all images in the system then copy them to a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

This is the code I used.

```
find . -regex '.*\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|gif\)' \! -path './ToutesImages/*' -exec echo cp -t ToutesImages {} +
```

[This is the terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llg0D.png)

Because it shows me all images in the system and echoes my code i guess something with the `-exec echo cp -t ToutesImages {} +` is wrong. Does anyone know how I can improve this?

[File manager. Just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZPep.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `echo` is there as a dry run so you can preview the command that will be executed. If it looks like the right set of files then delete it to actually perform the copy.